# How to combine formulas

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel

Can someone help me to combine these formulas to produce the desire result.

```
=IF(AND(D18>=N18,D18<=O18),M18,"")

=IF(AND(D19>=N19,D19<=O19),M19,"")

=IF(AND(D20>=N20,D20<=O20),M20,"")
```

I am trying to achieve certain value for each Range. e.g. if the value is between 0-29 it must equal 15, and then if the value is between 29-49 it must equal 12, and so on.

Comment: You know how to do it and don't know that you know.  In the first IF, you have the value if true and a null if false.  Replace the null with the next IF test.  In that one, replace the null with the next IF test.  So if it doesn't meet the first condition, it tests the second, and so on.  But it looks like you actually want to test one value against three different ranges, rather than testing three different values, so D18 for all three tests.

Answer (score 0):

As Fixer1234 said in his comment, just nest the `IF()` statements:

```
=IF(AND(D18>=N18,D18<=O18),M18,IF(AND(D19>=N19,D19<=O19),M19,IF(AND(D20>=N20,D20<=O20),M20,"")))
```

Comment: Plus some more parentheses.  Also the question mentions comparing "the" value, but the OP's attempt compares values in three different cells, so you might want to address that.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're an Office 365 subscriber, you can try IFS function in Excel:

```
=IFS(AND(D18>=N18,D18<=O18),M18,AND(D19>=N19,D19<=O19),M19,AND(D20>=N20,D20<=O20),M20)
```